# magento 2 cant login via admin despite following several threads

Tags: magento2, admin, login

I have a real stumper, I cannot access admin despite knowing the password is correct

1. I have followed the **magento 2** steps to reset password via email - I don't get the email resend request
2. I have done the SQL change and followed step by step from this link: ***https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/optimization-and-configuration/magento1/resetting-the-magento-administrator-password#Magento-2*** which outlines how to update the SQL password using the cryptographic salt.
3. I have unlocked the only **admin user** via **shell**
4. I have created a **new use**r via **SQL** which is live in SQL but produces the same error "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled"

I cant think of anything else to try! I know my Password is correct, i know the password for the SQL user i made is correct!

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

How about trying to create user using command line?

Login to your SSH and use following command:

```
bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="password123" --admin-email="admin@mydomains.com" --admin-firstname="Name" --admin-lastname="Surname"
```

Comment: thank you, i added this one, even though i added one before - did this and now im in! i had to reset all my user passwords through magento and now it works thank you ever so much